# Comparing array of structs, and removing duplicate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, struct, duplicates

I have two arrays of structs.

```
array_of_structs1
array_of_structs2
```

The struct class looks like this, for contextual info:

```
class Leader < Struct.new(:rank, :user); end
```

I want to remove the duplicate users from **array_of_structs1**.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand. If you want to remove duplicate structs that have the same user in array_of_struct1 use:

```
array_of_structs1 = Hash[*array_of_structs1.map {|obj| [obj.user, obj]}.flatten].values
```

If you wan't to remove entries from array1 that are also in array 2 use

```
array_of_structs1 = array_of_structs1 - array_of_struct2
```